# The laravel project is not working in "http://localhost/public/" the page says "This page isn’t working"

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, public

The laravel project is not working in `"http://localhost/public/`  folder in OpenServer localhost. However it works pretty well with php artisan server on localhost/8000. But I need that project in my localhost and for further deployments.[

screenshot of how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Enable debugging so you can see why you are hitting an error 500

Answer (score 2):

You need to config a server as stated in the [Laravel documentation/ web server configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#web-server-configuration).

If you want to config apache as your server you should add following lines in the `/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/{user}/{project_root}/public

    ServerName example.local
    ServerAlias www.example.local

    <Directory /home/{user}/{project_root}/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Insert your user name in the `{user}` and your desired domain in the `{example}`.

Then, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.

After that, add an ip in the `/etc/hosts` to your desired domain like below:

```
127.0.0.1 example.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost give access to your

- `htdocs` folder *(if using xamp)*
- `www` folder *(is using wamp)*

You need to add project name also in your url

Example:

`http://localhost/<project_name>/public`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my project already in localhost which is perfectly working for other static projects. The problem comes when I open laravel project